# Changing Xml Element Name Dynamically?

Tags: c#, xml, generics, reflection

I am trying to change Xml element name based on a rule during serialization.

Of course,I can manually add ElementName attribute manually but I have more than 1000 property in my class to be serialized.

In addition to that I don't want to change all property names only some of them which don't have Xml ElementName attribute.

For Instance ;

```
public class ToBeSerialized()
{
public string FirstName {get;set;}
public string LastName {get;set;}

[XmlElement(ElementName = "MyHome")]
public string Home {get;set;}

}
```

My Naming Convention for the ones don't have ElementName attribute.

```
public string ChangeName(string item)
{
   if (!propName.Any(p => char.IsLower(p)))
            {
                return propName;
            }

            var builder = new StringBuilder();

            for (int i = 0; i < propName.Length; i++)
            {
                if (i != 0 && char.IsUpper(propName[i]))
                {
                    builder.Append("_");
                }

                builder.Append(propName[i].ToString().ToUpper(new CultureInfo("en-US", false)));
            }

            return builder.ToString();
}
```

Desired Xml

```
<ToBeSerialized First_Name="Name" Last_Name="Surname" MyHome="Mine" />
```

Answer (score 0):

**Here is my solution.**
Walk throughout object properties check if it has already have XmlElementAttribute and ElementName of it has been set.

If it so don't change its name else change it name.

```
foreach (var prop in myObject.GetType().GetProperties())
            {
                var attribute = Attribute.GetCustomAttribute(prop, typeof(XmlElementAttribute)) as XmlElementAttribute;


                    XmlElementAttribute myElementAttribute = new XmlElementAttribute();
                    XmlAttributes myAttributes = new XmlAttributes();
                    if (attribute==null||attribute.ElementName.IsNullOrEmpty())
                    {
                        myElementAttribute.ElementName = prop.Name.NameToUpper();
                    }
                    if (prop.PropertyType == typeof(string))
                    {
                        myElementAttribute.IsNullable = true;
                    }
                    myAttributes.XmlElements.Add(myElementAttribute);
                    myOverrides.Add(typeof(myObject), prop.Name, myAttributes);
       }
```

Comment: I think the main issue with this solution is its use of reflection, which could be pretty costly on the processing power.